# Remover a parte debaixo do RadialGauge

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli

Tenho um gaugechart onde foi montado em um angulo de 180º, mais o mesmo continua mostrando os 360º, assim ocupando um espaço desnecessário.
 Como consigo remover essa parte debaixo do gráfico ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Segue jsfiddle com gauge funcionando](https://jsfiddle.net/otacio_barbosa/ueLph4rj/4/)

> Links da API que estou usando:

[canvas-gauges.com](https://canvas-gauges.com/download/)

[All Configuration Options](https://canvas-gauges.com/documentation/user-guide/configuration)